# How to switch to iframe window?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an iframe popup window, but can not get it in focus.

Here is the popup window and the button I am trying to click:

[image: pop up]

Here is the code I have so far:

patsearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="command_idSearchButton"]/nobr').click()

```
    time.sleep(5)

    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe_52"]')

    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    mrn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_15"]'))).send_keys(mrnum)
    time.sleep(1)

    ln = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_18"]'))).send_keys(last_name)
    time.sleep(1)

    fn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_19"]'))).send_keys(first_name)
    time.sleep(1)

    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_66"]'))).click()






    #try: click patient if one exists / try warning pop alert / exception warning / exception nopatient exists wrtie to file

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="idHTMLResult"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a'))).click()


        try:
            print('trying to switch..')

            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "frame_116")))
            print('switched')

            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_8"]')))

            driver.switch_to_default_content()
        except TimeoutException:
            print('didnt switch...')
```

Here is the HTML:

[image: html]

Solution:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe_52"]')

    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    #do something

#try: click account if one exists / try warning pop alert / exception warning / exception no account exists write to file

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="idHTMLResult"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a'))).click()


        try:
            driver.switch_to_default_content()
            print('trying to switch..')

            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "frame_116")))
            print('switched')

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_8"]'))).click()

            driver.switch_to_default_content()
        except:
            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code in question.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: error isselenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="frame_116"]"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the explicit wait for locating `iframe` and switching to it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "frame_116")))
```

PS: This code will replace the following lines:

```
warning = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frame_116"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(warning)
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks.

 I tried this, but had no success, I tried increasing the 10 to 30, but still nothing.

Comment: it timed out and resulted in:

_01-27-2019_11:06:51_
_trying to switch.._
_didnt switch..._

from code:

`try:
    print('trying to switch..')
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "frame_116")))
    print('switched')
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="control_8"]')))

    driver.switch_to_default_content()
   except TimeoutException:
    print('didnt switch...')`

Comment: So, your `iframe` is dynamic? Check your previous steps which are the result of appearances of `iframe` on the page.

Comment: I assume so, the warning alert window is generated by a floating div, which contains the iframe.

Comment: So, when it happens? (After which action?) After the first click on the link in your code?

Comment: this is the solution, the error was due to being in frame 52, and not switching to default content, before selecting frame 116.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this and check whether it works.instead of ID can you try with class name and check whether it works.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "modalGroupIframe")))


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modalGroupIframe"]')
```